# Receiving error - request for member ****** in not a structure or union

Tags: c, struct

I am making a generic Queue in C and am receiving the error in title. The functions in my Queue.c file are intended to be receiving initialized pointers.

Here is my struct code:

```
struct QueueNode {

   struct QueueNode *prev;
   struct QueueNode *next;

};

typedef struct QueueNode QNode;

struct Queue {

    QNode front;
    QNode rear;
};

typedef struct Queue Q;
```

Then in my Queue init function, I get the error. Here is my function:

```
void Q_Init(Q* const pointerQ){

    assert (pointerQ != NULL);   

    pointerQ.front->prev = NULL;
    pointerQ.front->next= pointerQ.rear;
    pointerQ.rear->prev = pointerQ.front;
    pointerQ.rear->prev = NULL;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why I am getting the error. I thought that since Queue has Node members and not pointers, I have to use pointerQ.front/rear to access them and then since Node has pointer members I then use ->next/rear.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pretty sure you're supposed to have some kind of data member in your nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I'd upvote but I dot have enough rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got things exactly backwards.  It's whether what's on the left is a struct or pointer to struct which determines whether to use '.' or '->' not what's on the right.

In your case pointerQ is a pointer to struct so you use '->' to access its fields:

```
pointerQ->front
pointerQ->rear
```

Since front & rear are struct instances, not pointers, you access their fields with '.':

```
pointerQ->front.prev = NULL;
pointerQ->front.next = pointerQ->rear;
pointerQ->rear.prev = pointerQ->front;
pointerQ->rear.next = NULL;
```

Once you've fixed that you're likely to get errors on the 2nd and 3rd assignments because the left hand side is a struct QueueNode * and the right hand side is a Qnode (which is a struct QueueNode).

To fix this you need:

```
pointerQ->front.next = &(pointerQ->rear);
pointerQ->rear.prev = &(pointerQ->front);
```

to take the addresses of front and rear.

Comment: I changed it and I am now getting the error: incompatible types when assigning to type struct QueueNode* from type QNode.

Answer (score 0):

`pointerQ.front` and so on should be `pointerQ->front`, since `pointerQ` is, as its name suggests, a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have to use `.` operator or `->` operator depends on what stands *to the left* of the operator, not on what stands to the right.

Your `pointerQ` is a pointer. You can't use `.` operator with a pointer, you have to use `->` or `*` and `.` combination.

Meanwhile, the situation with your `front` and `rear` members is the exact opposite. These members are not pointers. They are declared as objects of `struct QueueNode` type. You cannot use them with `->` operator. You have to use `.` operator to access their innards.

For example, this is a valid member access syntax `pointerQ->front.prev`. This is valid as well `(*pointerQ).front.prev`. What you have in your code is not valid.

Comment: I changed it and I am now getting the error: incompatible types when assigning to type struct QueueNode* from type QNode